# Django Users not showing the date_of_birth in the admin site

Tags: python, django

I am registering users by sending token activation email using built-in **register** and **activate** functions. The register form subclass the UserCreationForm to add extra fields for **email** and **date_of_birth** validations. My code is the following:

forms.py:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(years=range(2017, 1900, -1)))
email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=username).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('Username already exists')
    return username

def clean_date_of_birth(self):
    '''
    Only accept users aged 13 and above
    '''
    userAge = 13
    dob = self.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
    today = date.today()
    if (dob.year + userAge, dob.month, dob.day) > (today.year, today.month, today.day):
        raise forms.ValidationError('Users must be aged {} years old or above.'.format(userAge))
    return dob

def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    if User.objects.filter(email__iexact=email).exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError('A user has already registered using this email')
    return email

def clean_password2(self):
    '''
    we must ensure that both passwords are identical
    '''
    password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
    password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
    if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Passwords must match')
    return password2

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'password1', 'password2']
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():
          email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
          date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
          new_user = form.save(commit=False)
          new_user.is_active = False
          new_user.save()
          current_site = get_current_site(request)
          message = render_to_string('email_activation_link.html', {
            'new_user':new_user,
            'domain':current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(new_user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(new_user),
          })
          mail_subject = 'Activate your Frac account.'
          to_email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[email])
          to_email.send()
        return render(request, 'register_confirm.html', {'form': form})
   else:
      form = UserRegisterForm()

   return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})


def activate(request, uidb64, token):
   try:
       uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
       new_user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
   except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
       new_user = None
   if new_user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(new_user, token):
      new_user.is_active = True
      new_user.save()
      return render(request, 'register_complete.html', {})
   else:
      return render(request, 'registration_incomplete.html', {})
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   '''
   Extends the Django User model
   '''
   user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                            related_name='profile')
   email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
   date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   profile_photo = models.ImageField(blank=True)
   following = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    blank=True,
                                    related_name='followed_by')

   def __str__(self):
       return 'Followers({});Following({})'.format(self.user.followed_by.all().count(),self.get_following().count())

def post_save_user_receiver(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
   '''
   Django signals to automatically create
   a user profile when a user object is created
   '''
   if created:
       new_profile, is_created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(post_save_user_receiver, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import UserProfile

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'id', 'date_of_birth', 'profile_photo', '__str__']


admin.site.register(UserProfile, ProfileAdmin)
```

The new user is registered properly. However, only the **username** and **email** fields appear in Users section of the Django admin site. I can't figure out why the **date_of_birth** field is not showing for the newly-registered user.

Comment: Please show your user model and admin class.

Comment: And  please indent your code properly.

Comment: Dear all, I included models.py and admin.py. I formatted my code as cezar suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `date_of_birth` field belongs to the `UserProfile` model, so you should not include it in your user form's `fields`.

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']
```

In your view, you can get the profile that was created by your signal, and set the date of birth, which you can get from the cleaned data.

```
   if form.is_valid():
      email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
      date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
      new_user = form.save(commit=False)
      new_user.is_active = False
      new_user.save()
      profile = new_user.profile
      profile.date_of_birth=date_of_birth
      profile.save()
```

Comment: Dear Alasdair, thank you for the response. I understand better my mistake. Similar to Daniel's, implementing your code causes the error: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id

Comment: I can't help because you haven't said whether or not you are using a signal to create the user profile, and you haven't shown the full traceback. If you are using a signal to create the user profile, you should use the second snippet with `profile = new_user.userprofile`. That should not cause a unique constraint error.

Comment: I am using a signal to create the user profile (edited models.py). The second method is the way to go. Funny though the date of birth is still not displayed, which brings us to the original issue.

Comment: Hence my question !!!! Anyway the error was in the last piece of code you provided. The profile.save  should be profile.save(). Thank you so much for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't extended the user model, you've added a related user profile. You don't do anything anywhere to actually create instances of this user profile or populate them with the data from the form; you get the DOB and email values in your view but then proceed to ignore them.

You need to create a Profile with those values:

```
   if form.is_valid():
      new_user = form.save(commit=False)
      new_user.is_active = False
      new_user.save()
      email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
      date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
      UserProfile.objects.create(user=new_user, email=email, date_of_birth=date_of_birth)
```

Comment: Dear Daniel, Thank you for the response. However, I cannot grasp why this error happens: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_userprofile.user_id